# How to FIX implicit any of array access of property

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I have this code:

```js
function getKey(): string {
    return 'foo';
}

function dummy(): void {
    const object = {};
    const key: string = getKey();
    const value: any = 42;

    object[key] = value; // ERROR: TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
}
```

I know the error exists because I have enabled the `noImplicitAny` for cleaner code but how is the clean way to set this property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a `Record` type :

```js
function getKey(): string {
    return 'foo';
}

function dummy(): void {
    const object: Record<string, any> = {}; // Here you can define the type of value, example string or number.
    const key: string = getKey();
    const value: any = 42;

    object[key] = value; // Not error
}
```